# scsi_eh_320 process eating +90% cpu on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 64bits

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, ubuntu-12.04

This is a virtual machine running on ESXi. The server is connected to an HP Storage.

The VM starts, then after a couple of minutes (with `top` running) the process scsi_eh_320 starts and eats +90% of CPU and keeps there.

Does anyone know what can be causing this?.

**EDIT**

Found this in my db:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sys_eval(text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE c
 IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS '/tmp/gameover.so', $function$sys_eval$function$
```

Comment: It seems to be a binary script (placed by an attacker)
/tmp/scsi_eh_320 Haven't found the source.

Comment: Yes it is placed in /tmp/scsi_eh_320

Answer (score 4):

I have the same process on one of my server. I kill it and i delete these files and directories fom /tmp:

config.f
conf.n  \
facebook
gameover.so
Loader.sh
Run.sh
scsi_eh_320

They are all done by user "postgres". I search some malware function (\df+) in postgres database but i don't find nothing. The port 5432 is accessible from the internet so I think they use this way to infect.

Comment: I had exactly the same files/directories in /tmp, I deleted them, killed the process and restricted the access in pg_hba.conf